# Открытие файла в webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5, webkit

В node-webkit хочу открывать по выбору из папки страницы формата .html содержащие определенные данные (заранее ссылаться не выходит, ибо файлы постоянно добавляются,заменяются и т.д). Форма работает на открытие каталога и выбора файла из списка, но на этом все заканчивается, на пустой страничке отображается fileX.html. Есть способ чтобы страница открывалась из файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос используя `fs.reddir` и выводя список файлов как ссылки

```js
files.forEach(file  => {
    document.write("<a href=" + "'" + "udostoverenia/" + file + "'>" + file + "</a>" + "</br>");
  });
```